# Implementing operator<=> for optional<T>

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

With `operator<=>` being added into C++20, I wanted to try to reason about how to implement this operator for those cases where it's not a simple member-wise comparison.

How would you implement the spaceship operator for comparing an `optional<T>` to an `optional<U>`or a `U`, which is a case where we either have to compare the `T` to the `U` or compare underlying states, getting the correct return type? There isn't such an example in the [latest paper](http://wg21.link/p0515).

Comment: BTW the feature is incompatible with `a>>operator<=>>c;` that currently can be valid.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes, it is. That’s also mentioned in the proposal: “Tokenization follows max munch as usual. [...] This is the only known backward source incompatibility, and it is intentional. (We
could adopt a special parsing rule to keep such code working without a space, but I would discourage
that as having too little benefit for the trouble.)”. Seeing as you would usually have a space and/or parentheses there anyway, I think I agree with the proposal here.

Comment: @Barry it isn't mentioned in the proposal, as far as I can see (it only gives a following comparison, but not a following switch, as backward incompatiblity. and it says "this is the only known backward source incompatibility")

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb 1. Please check who you’re replying to; Barry didn’t say the proposal mentioned that, I did, and I almost missed your comment. 2. I assume you mean “a following shift”, since I don’t see how a following switch can cause an issue. 3. I read it as saying maximum munch is the only known backward source incompatibility, although I don’t know why Herb didn’t list shift as one of the two places he’s aware of maximum munch occurring.

Comment: (For reference, [here](https://godbolt.org/g/TsUzxX) is an example where maximum munch changes the tokenization in a shift expression)

Answer (score 12):

With `<=>` we have to make a decision: what do we want to do if the underlying comparison we need does not yet implement `<=>`?

One option is: don't care. Just use `<=>` and if the relevant types don't provide it, we're not comparable. That makes for a very concise implementation (note that you need to do the same thing for `==` for a total of six functions):

```
template <typename T>
class optional {
public:
    // ...

    template <typename U>
    constexpr std::compare_three_way_result_t<T, U>
    operator<=>(optional<U> const& rhs) const
    {
        if (has_value() && rhs) {
            return **this <=> *rhs;
        } else {
            return has_value() <=> rhs.has_value();
        }
    }

    template <typename U>
    constexpr std::compare_three_way_result_t<T, U>
    operator<=>(U const& rhs) const
    {
        if (has_value()) {
            return **this <=> *rhs;
        } else {
            return strong_ordering::less;
        }
    }

    constexpr strong_ordering operator<=>(nullopt_t ) const {
        return has_value() ? strong_ordering::greater
                           : strong_ordering::equal;
    }
};
```

The three-way comparison between `bool`s yields `std::strong_ordering`, which is implicitly convertible to the other comparison categories. Likewise, `strong_ordering::less` being implicitly convertible to `weak_ordering::less`, `partial_ordering::less`, `strong_equality::unequal`, or `weak_equality::nonequivalent`, as appropriate.

The above is the super nice, happy answer. And hopefully as time progresses, people will adopt `<=>` and more and more code will be able to rely on the happy answer.

---

Another option is: we do care, and want to fallback to synthesizing an ordering. That is, if we need to compare a `T` and a `U` and they don't provide a `<=>`, we can use one of the new customization point objects in the standard library. Which one though? The most conservative option is to synthesize a `partial_ordering` with `compare_partial_order_fallback`. This guarantees that we will always get the right answer.

For the `optional<T>` vs `optional<U>` comparison, that looks like:

```
template <typename T>
class optional {
public:
    // ...

    template <typename U>
    constexpr auto operator<=>(optional<U> const& rhs) const
        -> decltype(std::compare_partial_order_fallback(**this, *rhs))
    {
        if (has_value() && rhs) {
            return std::compare_partial_order_fallback(**this, *rhs);
        } else {
            return has_value() <=> rhs.has_value();
        }
    }

    // ...
};
```

Unfortunately, as implemented above, our comparison now always returns `partial_ordering` -- even between two `optional<int>`s. So a better alternative might be to use whatever `<=>` returns and use the conservative fallback otherwise. I have no idea how to name this concept yet, so I'll just go with:

```
template <typename T, std::three_way_comparable_with<T> U>
constexpr auto spaceship_or_fallback(T const& t, U const& u) {
    return t <=> u;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto spaceship_or_fallback(T const& t, U const& u)
    -> decltype(std::compare_partial_order_fallback(t, u))
{
    return std::compare_partial_order_fallback(t, u);
}
```

and use that:

```
template <typename T>
class optional {
public:
    // ...

    template <typename U>
    constexpr auto operator<=>(optional<U> const& rhs) const
        -> decltype(spaceship_or_fallback(**this, *rhs))
    {
        if (has_value() && rhs) {
            return spaceship_or_fallback(**this, *rhs);
        } else {
            return has_value() <=> rhs.has_value();
        }
    }

    // ...
};
```

---

A third option, the most conservative option, is what the Standard Library will take. Provide *both* the relational operators *and* the three-way comparison:

```
template <typename T> class optional { /* ... */ };

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool operator<(optional<T> const&, optional<U> const&);
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool operator>(optional<T> const&, optional<U> const&);
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool operator<=(optional<T> const&, optional<U> const&);
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool operator>=(optional<T> const&, optional<U> const&);

template <typename T, std::three_way_comparable_with<T> U>
std::compare_three_way_result_t<T, U>
operator<=>(optional<T> const& x, optional<U> const& y) {
    if (x && y) {
        return *x <=> *y;
    } else {
        return x.has_value() <=> y.has_value();
    }
}
```

This is the most conservative option as it effectively takes both the C++17-and-earlier comparison implementation strategy *and* the C++20 comparison implementation strategy. As in: the "Why not both?" strategy. The use of the `concept` on `operator<=>` is what ensures that `a < b` invokes `<=>` where possible, instead of `<`.

It's by far the most tedious and verbose approach, with lots of boilerplate, but it ensures that for existing, single-object comparison types, existing comparisons continue to work and do the same thing. The standard library has to be conservative like this.

But new code doesn't.

Comment: Here you’re calling `*lhs` and `*rhs` when you know one of them is empty. Also, why are you implementing this as a non-member when `operator<=>` is intended to be implemented as a member?

Comment: @DanielH I fixed his typo in the 2nd comparison

Comment: (I also feel like calling `has_value` is clearer than the explicit cast to `bool`, but that’s a matter of style)

Comment: @DanielH Why in the world do you think it is "intended to be implemented as a member"?  My complaint would rather be "why are you a template on both, and not a koenig operator".

Comment: @Yakk Thanks! And it states as such in the paper. I just wrote it as a non-member for clarity and not having to write `**this`

Comment: @Yakk Because of the note on page 3 of the proposal which says “Normally, `operator<=>` should be just a member function; you will still get conversions on each parameter because of the symmetric generation rules in §2.3.”, right above the start of section 1.4.1.

Comment: @Yakk I missed your edit. Presumably you template on both so that if you have optionals of two different but comparable types, like `string` and `string_view`, you can still compare them.

Comment: @DanielH I get why you have to have that, but my problem is that by templating on both you cannot support types that can implicitly convert-to optional on either side of the `<=>`.  As an example, try streaming `struct hello_world { operator std::string() const { return "hello world"; } }` to `std::ostream` and watch it break because `<<` in question is "over-templated".

Comment: @Yakk Would that be solvable by adding a non-template overload for `optional<T>` specifically?

Comment: @DanielH You could constrain the second template to types which are not convertible to `optional<T>` and keep the first one as is.

Comment: Why not implement the `optional<T> <=> optional<U>` case using the `optional<T> <=> U` case? E.g. `if(has_value()) return **this <=> rhs; else return has_value() <=> rhs.has_value();`

Comment: @dyp You could, but I don't see the benefit? Doesn't save you any code.

Comment: I'm a bit aggressive against code duplication lately, and this `compare_3way` is repeated four times; we could drop two of them. I guess you could even implement all comparison functions using a single implementation, if `optional<T&>` was supported (wrap `U const&` -> `optional<U const&>`).

Comment: I was musing about sum/product types, and it makes me think your code should have a `if (auto kind = (has_value() <=> rhs.has_value())` directly in it. (or does it need a `;kind==0`?)